# I need to have a variable IN my variable name, not AS my variable name

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, for-loop

How would I do that?

According to PHP.net,

```
$a = "hi";
$hi = 2;
$$a; // returns 2
```

However, I need:

```
$i = 2;
$_POST['link$i'];  // I need this to return the same thing as $_POST['link2']
```

Here is how I have my code.

```
      for ($i = 1; $i <= 40; $i++)
      {
        if(!empty($link$i))
        {
        $link$i = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['link$i']);
        mysql_query("
          INSERT INTO links (link, rimageid) VALUES
          ('".$link$i."', '".$id."') ");
        } else { }
      }
```

The reason I'm doing this is because I have a lot of text input fields posting their values to this file, and I'd like to define and insert each of their values via a for loop instead of manually inserting each single link into mysql.

Right now, I get:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\new2.php on line 22
```

How would I go about doing this?
Thanks!

Comment: Variable interpolation works in [double quoted strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double), not in single quotes. So `$_POST["link$i"]` would be the language built-in for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For array index concatenation, ok, but this code

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 40; $i++)
      {
        if(!empty($link$i))
        {
        $link$i = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['link$i']);
        mysql_query("
          INSERT INTO links (link, rimageid) VALUES
          ('".$link$i."', '".$id."') ");
        } else { }
      }
```

won't work as you expect, i.e. name a variable like the result it's not necessary, why would you want to do that? PHP doesn't care about the variable name and if it's coordinated with the result.

Just do:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 40; $i++)
      {
      if(!empty($_POST['link'.$i]))
      {
        $regular_variable_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['link'.$i]);
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO links (link, rimageid) VALUES ('".$regular_variable_name."', '".$id."') ");
        } else { }
      }
```

Comment: Wow, that makes a lot of sense. A tad sleep deprived here.

Answer (score 2):

How about string concatenation?

```
$_POST['link'.$i];
```

Comment: please see my comment to the above answer

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving a syntax error because `$link$i` is not valid.

if you want the end value to be `link2` then you need a solution like Nick Shepherd suggested.

It could be easier to see what is going on if you create the string that you want for the key first.

```
$key = 'link' . $i;
```

After that you can use the key whenever you want, in a conditional like

```
if (!empty($_POST[$key])) {
```

and again in your mysql_escape

```
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$key]);
```

Comment: OH, I see now what he's saying. Basically, don't define it and just use the $_POST['link' . $i]; in the if-statement. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_POST['link' . $i];
```

This should solve your problem.  For indexes of an array you can simply concatenate the string for the index that you are trying to resolve.

Comment: What about for the if-statement part, $link$i?

Answer (score 0):

yep... you can do the following

```
$ = 2;
$link = "link" . $i;
if(isset($_POST[$link])){
     //do something
}
```

or

```
$_POST[$link.$i]
```

the same goes for methods

```
$type = "Something";
$method = "get" . $type;

$this->$method();   //calls method -> getSomething()
```

Comment: Thanks. This will help later on in this script.